# ¿Por qué no funciona variables de session en servidor de nuevo? PHP

Tags: php

buen día.

Tengo un sistema hecho en PHP.
Anteriormente estaba en un hosting web, pero al ser tan grande, lo pasé un servidor dedicado.

```
$_SESSION["usuario"] = array();
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["id"] = $row["id"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["user"] = $row["user"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["email"] = $row["email"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["nombre"] = $row["nombre"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["apellido"] = $row["apellido"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["tipo"] = $row["tipo"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"]["campos"] = $row["config_tabla_asig"];
```

Por ejemplo, cuando uno se loguea, debería crear la variable de session "usuario".

Cuando la imprimo, la misma me aparece como "array()".

Comment: Cómo la estás imprimiendo? Probaste con `print_r($_SESSION["usuario"]);`?

Comment: Revisa si `session.save_path` está seteado en el nuevo server.